# Convert a string of list to a proper list

Tags: python, string

I have the following:

```
a = """\"[""123456789"",""987654321""]\""""
```

I am trying to convert that to a list of strings. I've tried the following:

```
lst = ast.literal_eval(a)
```

but this returns all the characters as an individual string. What is the mistake I am doing?

The expected output: `["123456789", "987654321"]`

Comment: "this returns all the characters as individual strings" - actually, it doesn't. It returns a single string, and that's because the whole thing is wrapped in quotes. It's the same reason that `[5, 6]` is a list of ints, but `"[5, 6]"` is a single string.

Comment: @slothrop that's what i wanted to say. Incorrect wording on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `literal_eval` twice to get a list of integers and then map each integer to strings like this :

```
from ast import literal_eval as le
lst = le(le(a))
lst = list(map(str, lst))
```

`lst` would now become `['123456789', '987654321']`